# Rails assets - keep license comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

How can I prevent Uglifier from removing some comments from some files? I want to have code minified and compressed but also I want the licensing comments to remain intact.

Comment: When I look at uglifier I see that the default option is to keep the copyright statements at the top of files, are your copyright statements presented as comments at the top of files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation of uglifyJS.

> `-nc` or `--no-copyright` — by default, uglifyjs will keep the initial comment tokens in the generated code (assumed to be copyright information etc.). If you pass this it will discard it.

which is also an option of uglifier.

Comment: And how to pass it to `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: Put to your `production.rb`: `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:copyright => true)`

Comment: Yes but that's `false` that is wanted here.