# Rails assets keep CSS license comments when stylesheet assets are minified

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How do I preserve CSS comments in Rails stylesheet assets that are minified?

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896969/rails-assets-keep-license-comments), but for CSS instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails currently uses [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to minify CSS stylesheets during asset precompilation. See [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-compression) of the Rails asset guide.

To prevent certain comments from being removed, just add an exclamation point to the comment block as follows:

```
/*!

License comment here won't be removed

*/
```

This is documented [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/css.html#min).

Comment: Is it possible delete comments with `Yui compressor` or `sass-rails` of comments with `/*!` an exclamation point before of css?

Thanks!